# How long is too long data for any column in MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, string, sqldatatypes, maxlength

I was trying to insert some **string values** to a column `column1` in mysql table using C#.

The values can keep changing every time.

Sometimes the application throws `Data too long` exception.

I went through some posts:

- ["Data too long for column" - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897420/data-too-long-for-column-why)
- [Data truncation: Data too long for column 'logo' at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522875/data-truncation-data-too-long-for-column-logo-at-row-1)
- [mysql- Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'description' at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350132/mysql-mysql2error-data-too-long-for-column-description-at-row-1)
- [Data truncation: Data too long for column 'Phone' at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699138/data-truncation-data-too-long-for-column-phone-at-row-1)
- [MySQL data too long error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37481/mysql-data-too-long-error)

But my question is:

> How can I programmatically decide how long string (or other data type) value is too long for a mysql column.

So that if the data is too long and cannot be inserted, I can manually truncate less useful data.

Comment: You can use [`SHOW COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html) query to get information about the type and size for the specified columns, then you'll know how much data can fit in the particular column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done in your db. The database structure tells you what is to long. The errors you're getting are coming from the database.

So the decision is when the database was created.

1. either change the database or
2. check the structure of the database to consult yourself what `limits` are set
3. change the code accordingly

**Update**
As you question changed:

To truncate your data, see step 2 from above, use that info to truncate.